# Use jQuery to update CSS background if it has changed on server

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, background

I am trying to use jQuery to update a div's background dynamically if it has changed on the server (i.e. so that the page can remain open and the background image will refresh).

I have the following code which works for the #current div contents, but not the background image of #banner.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get('/index.php',function(data){
        $('#current').empty().append($('#current_refresh',data));
        var banner_bg = $(data).filter( $('#banner').css('background-image') );
        $('#banner').css('backgroundImage',banner_bg);
    });
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
$(data).filter( $('#banner').css('background-image') );
```

jQuery's filter works on elements, but this is trying to filter the returned string from `css()`.

To get the background image from the inline styles on the element you'd do:

```
$.get('/index.php',function(data){
    $('#current').empty().append($('#current_refresh',data));

    var banner_bg = $('<div />', {html:data}).find('#banner').css('background-image');

    $('#banner').css('background-image', banner_bg);

});
```

This of course only works on an element looking something like :

```
<div id="banner" style="background-image: url('image.jpg')"></div>
```

and doesn't get styles from stylesheets etc ?

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks mate, I'll accept your answer as soon as I can. Cheers :)